# Phabricator: advantage/disadvantage of hosted repository?

Tags: git, phabricator

Our company currently uses [phabricator](http://phabricator.org/) with a non-hosted SVN repository.

We are switching from a single `SVN` repo to a `git` repo-per-project.

Is there any advantage to be had from having the repo's hosted by [phabricator](http://phabricator.org/)?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the benefit is the better integration with Phabricator.
For example landing to GitHub from the Differential page, is (currently) not possible. If you take a look at their setup, you can find some [tasks](https://secure.phabricator.com/T4482), where they describe it:

> **Hosting**
>
> - From 2011-2013, Phabricator's authoritative remote was a public GitHub
>     repository. We imported from GitHub into Diffusion. In modern
>     Phabricator, this is the "Import an Existing External Repository"
>     option, although it was the only option at the time.
> - In late 2013, shortly after we built repository hosting, we moved the primary 
>     to Phabricator itself, and configured an automatic mirror to GitHub in
>     Diffusion. This made it easier for us to control access, allowed us to
>     write Herald rules, and let us test the implementation. Most
>     Phabricator users still use the GitHub mirror (it auto-pushes a couple
>     seconds after the authoritative one gets updated).
> - The major advantages of hosted repositories are simplified access control,
>     access to pre-commit Herald rules, other pre-commit features (we'll
>     block --force pushes by default, for example), and the push log. Using
>     an imported repository instead has no impact on any of the
>     review/audit workflows.